# Conversion de una matriz deString a int en java

Tags: java

```
for( int  i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(usuario.equals(matriz[i][0])){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Encontrado");
        String n =matriz[1][0];
        int ju= Integer.parseInt(n);
        int vi= Integer.parseInt(matriz[2][0]);
        int ni= Integer.parseInt(matriz[3][0]);
        user = new Usuario(usuario,10,vi,ni);
        break;
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Encontrado");
    }
}
```

Comment: me salta error en la linea de los parseos

Comment: Podrías incluir los datos que tiene la matriz?

Comment: Si te sale error en las líneas de `parseInt()` debe ser porque no es estrictamente un número válido lo que se desea convertir. Compártenos el contenido de la matriz.

Comment: Hola Jhon. Para que tu pregunta sea de más calidad, por favor edita la pregunta para añadir informacion como los datos que intntas procesar y el problema concreto que tienes. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo